# Как заменить символы в строке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Необходимо написать программу которая заменяет измененные слова. Например, есть строка `"Ты ду_Р-ак или нет?"` в данной строке необходимо заменить подстроку `ду_Р-ак` на `***`.
Как написать регулярное выражение если пользователь будет пытаться схитрить и писать слово `"дурак"` через тире, нижний пробел или другие символы, или если часть слова будет написана на латинице а часть на кириллице.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String string = "Ты ду_рак или Дур_ак чудак?";

    String lower = string.toLowerCase();

    String pattern = "дурак";
    String p ="***";

    String newString = lower.replaceAll(pattern, p);
    System.out.println(newString);
}
```

Comment: Без глубокого синтаксического и грамматического анализа текста эта идея неосуществима в принципе. Примером тому - сотни попыток реализаций, начиная со знаменитого "матотеста" (гугл в помошь), и все - не особо удачные. Впрочем, скачать исходники матотеста-PHP, или перлового Lingua::RU::Censure не проблема. В любом случае на сегодня это лучшие реализации подобного подхода, смотрите как они устроены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю

```
[дd][\W_]?[уy][\W_]?[рpr][\W_]?[аa][\W_]?[кk]
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/qP2bP9/1) (необходимо использовать модификатор CASE_INSENSITIVE и UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).

**Пояснение**:

- `[дd]` - `д` или `d`
- `[\W_]?` - необязательный (`?` находит 1 или 0 совпадений) символ, отличный от букв и цифр
- `[уy]` - `р`, `p` или `r`
- `[\W_]?` - необязательный символ, отличный от букв и цифр
- `[рpr]` - `р`, `p` или `r`
- `[\W_]?` - необязательный символ, отличный от букв и цифр
- `[аa]` - `а` или `a`
- `[\W_]?` - необязательный символ, отличный от букв и цифр
- `[кk]` - `к` или `k`

Если "лишних" символов может быть больше одного, замените `?` на `*` в `[\W_]?`, а если нужно исключить пробел, можно использовать `[\W_&&[^\s]]?` (не забудьте о двойных обратных слешах в Java).

См. [демо на IDEONE](http://ideone.com/YrFrQF):

```
String string = "Ты ду_рак или Дур_ак чудак?";
String pattern = "(?iU)[дd][\\W_]?[уy][\\W_]?[рpr][\\W_]?[аa][\\W_]?[кk]";
String p ="***";
String newString = string.replaceAll(pattern, p);
System.out.println(newString);
```

Comment: А что насчёт "защиты от  ***а"?

Comment: @PinkTux: Поясните, пожалуйста. Тройную звездочку можно отловить с помощью `"\\*{3}"`, собственно, тут можно и `indexOf("***")` использовать.

Comment: я немного о другом. Прямую задачу это решает. Но - см. мой комментарий к посту. Если подумать на шаг вперёд, то база подобных регекспов будет немаленькой (и всё равно в двух указанных мной модулях она наиболее полная, так зачем изобретать велосипед?) А если на два шага вперёд, то я ещё не знаю ни одного случая, когда после массы ложных срабатываний на вполне невинные вещи, от этого подхода не отказывались бы...

Comment: Да, но если бы вопрос ставился глобально, его бы следовало закрыть, скорее всего, как "необходимо конкретизировать вопрос". А так - велосипеды изобретаются каждый день :)